# Adding an item to drop down list with Jquery at a certain index

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

Is this possible?

I use append like this

```
$(".ddl").append($("<option></option>").val("").text("Select"));
```

But this appends it at the end....

Comment: I know this is old but just in case others come across this question: 

You can use .prepend() if you want it to be the very first option, which I assume is what he wants since it is a Select option with no value.

`$(".ddl").prepend($("<option></option>").val("").text("Select"));`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

if you want to add on like index 2 you can do this:

```
$(".dll option").eq(2).before($("<option></option>").val("").text("Select"));
```

this means, select index 2, and put the new option before that one.

Answer (score 2):

Find the option at `.eq(n)` to specify the index you want the new option at.  Then use [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before) to insert the object.  (See also [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore), [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter), or [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after))

```
$(".ddl option").eq(n).before($("<option></option>").val("").text("Select"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the dll like `var dll = $(".dll")`

```
dll.children("option").eq(2).before($("<option></option>").val("").text("Select"));
```

Answer (score 0):

an alternative :

```
  <select name="nb_wanted">
    <option value="1" selected>1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
  </select>
```

jQuery :

```
    var new_option = 15;

    $('select[name="nb_wanted"] option').removeAttr("selected");

    var options_len = $('select[name="nb_wanted"] option').length;

    for (var i = 0; i < options_len; i++) {

          var val = $('select[name="nb_wanted"] option').eq(i).val()*1;

          if( val > new_option ){

                if( i != 0 && ( $('select[name="nb_wanted"] option').eq(i-1).val()*1 ) != new_option ){


                    $('select[name="nb_wanted"] option').eq(i)
                    .before('<option value="'+new_option+'" selected>'+new_option+'</option>');

                    break;
                }
                else if( i != 0 && ( $('select[name="nb_wanted"] option').eq(i-1).val()*1 ) == new_option ){

                    $('select[name="nb_wanted"] option').eq(i-1).prop( "selected", true );

                    break;
                }

          }
          // END IF if( val > new_option )

    }
    // END FOR
```

Hope to help someone ...